# Error parsing the package

Tags: android, android-studio

This error keeps comes on my phone but it did not come before,I saw all the stack overflow methods but non of them could help me.

I get this error when I test the app from android studio to my phone.I tried on other phones too but still the problem exist.

This is my **manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.patel.pritesh.smstimer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/sms_timer"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Time_Picker"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process="remote"
            android:taskAffinity="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SEND" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".NotificationReciever"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="notification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".deliveryReciever"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="notification_delivered" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".sms_list">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".sms_review" />

        <service
            android:name=".alarmService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This error comes in the run tab:

```
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "my.patel.pritesh.smstimer/my.patel.pritesh.smstimer.sms_list" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

Error while Launching activity

Comment: what is the error? post your locat

Comment: these is no error in logcat just it shows there is a problem parsing the package on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Main tag of manifest file must be manifest. Instead of xml tag, write something like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.dummy"
    android:versionCode="100"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/sms_timer"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

   ...
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: so do you mean I should remove the xml tag on top?

Comment: What's exactly the error on logcat? In your manifest i didn't see manifest tag. Do you have it?

Comment: I added the whole manifest file,I cant understand about the manifest tab.The tag<manifest> is there

Comment: I just noticed there is an error showing cannot resolver getDefaultProguardFile.How do i fix that.

Comment: Are you using proguard? Are you building debug version or release version of you apk? Try in debug flavor without proguard.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Android Studio, I believe that you are likely have the problem mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36802588/1638739), and as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36864172/1638739) in the answer this error happens when you change the build version for your project (like downgrading or upgrading):

> I've been working on this same exact problem for the last 8
>   hours...you've had no issues after rolling back from 2.0 to 1.5.1?
>
> I've noticed that, even with the error, running the app works fine
>   sometimes.

so you have to make sure that there is no problem with the new release you are using, then you have to clean and rebuild your project again like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37882554/1638739).

---

Or you can use the following hint from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36553688/1638739):

> Remove the .idea folder and gradle folder, then click button sync
>   project with gradle gradle files, after this process finished, you are
>   able to run your app as normal.