# Session app: Error launching Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I couldn't run app from Android studio.

**What I have tried**

1. Disabled Instant Run and tried.
2. Invalid caches/ Restart.. option tried.
3. Checked updates for Android studio, and its already latest version.
4. Checked updates for SDK, and updated Instant Apps Development SDK.
5. Generated singed APK on both V1 and V2 signature and tried installing, got `app not installed` error.
6. Generated singed APK only on V1 signature and tried installing, got `app not installed` error.
7. Generated singed APK only on V2 signature and tried installing, got `app not installed` error.
8. Cleaned device's cache memories and tried installing from Android studio, got `Session app: Error launching Activity in Android Studio` error.
9. Restarted device and tried again, got `Session app: Error launching Activity in Android Studio` error.

Now don't know what to do next and how to fix this issue.

Note: I am using `Nexus 5X`, Developer options enabled. USB debugging enabled,
OS : Android 8.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application is not completely uninstalled.

For me this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46398427/2638929) works, I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple just uninstall package using adb command after you connect to your device

```
adb uninstall PACKAGE NAME
```

replace “PACKAGE NAME” with the name of the application you want to delete and press “Enter.”