# I have just installed Android Studio again.. and run 'Hello world' App.. but occurred below

Tags: kotlin

02/06 11:28:03: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 30.
Install successfully finished in 23 s 634 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices

Please cheer me up. I am so disappointed... I did nothing since I have installed AS..sigh

I expected just Hello world on the emulator...

Comment: Fighting! Any chances to solve with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530648/session-app-error-launching-activity) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802588/error-while-launching-activity)?

Comment: lacks formatting and MainActivity code... quite difficult to argue what's going wrong.