# session app error launching an activity - how to fix that?

Tags: android

I have following error while installing app on real devices and emulator.

```
session-app-error-launching-activity-in-android-studio
```

I have tried below links but nothing comes

Even after creating new project, this error will come out.

1. [Session 'app': Error Launching activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530648/session-app-error-launching-activity#)
2. [Session app: Error launching Activity in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420638/session-app-error-launching-activity-in-android-studio)
   3.[Android Studio: Session 'app': Error Launching activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44216467/android-studio-session-app-error-launching-activity)
   4.[Error while Launching activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802588/error-while-launching-activity)
   5.[Session 'app': Error Launching activity in Android Studio 3.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770748/session-app-error-launching-activity-in-android-studio-3-1-3)

Here is my manifest file code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.efunhub.neworganicveg">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

  </manifest>
```

screenshot of Edit Configuration window
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the error log ?

Comment: Didn't get any kind of exception, app not get install while i am trying to get install it on devices

Comment: change the default activity to mainactivity in launch option

Comment: okay will follow that and let you know thanks.

Comment: @GaneshGudghe i have tried your scenario but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Invalid cache/ Restart trying doing it hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution instead of disabling `instant run`. Remove the `.idea` folder and `.gradle` folder, then click button `sync project with gradle files`, after this process finished, you are able to run your app as normal.

Good Luck~

Comment: Did it helped..?