# Empty activity project - Error while Launching activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm creating a new project with android studio (with empty activity).
I'm not doing any change to the code (use all the defaults), and when I try to run it I get "Error while Launching activity", but the app starts on my device. when trying to start debug, the app is stuck on "waiting for debugger"
this is the log I get in the "Run" tab:

> $ adb shell am start -n "com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Error while executing: am start -n "com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.test.testapp/.MainActivity }
>
> Error while Launching activity

I've tried everything solution suggested to this issue (disable Instant Run, add -r to install flags, delete .idea, clean, invalidate cache) and everything suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530648/session-app-error-launching-activity) but nothing works.
I'm trying this on a brand new Macbook Pro, with android studio 2.3.3. I had the same issue with my old laptop, so don't think it is a hardware issue. any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: So, you are saying app works on device but not on emulator??

Comment: how are you trying to run the app? with the run button, or with some adb command? are you using an emulator or a connected device?

Comment: this happens on both the emulator and a real device. trying to run it from the android studio run button

Comment: what happens if you enter the following directly into the terminal in Android Studio?
`adb shell am start -n "com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.MainActivity"`

Comment: running adb from terminal works without error