# I can not see hello world app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hi I have installed Android studio correctly. I made AVD for e.q Marshmallow and project on the same platform. after press RUN, AVD turns on. I can do everything on emulated android phone(other issue- after running this my computer dramticly slowing down) but I should see my "Hello world" app, there is not there. I'm getting following error

> Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.zad2/com.example.zad2.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
> Error while Launching activity

where zad2 is my project name.

On Stacfoverflow i saw tips to add into manifest some filter code but I already have it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Zad2">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yea don't trouble friends. I found this post: [Session 'app': Error Launching activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530648/session-app-error-launching-activity/47352644)
and I unistalled my app from AVD :)